# How to get links and bold notation from a XML file while parsing using php?

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activities>
<activity category="Team">
<date><h4>Date: January 15, 2017</h4></date>
<work> 
    <li><b>MR X</b> working on X</li>
    <li><b>MR Y</b> working on Y</li>
    <li><b>MR Z</b> working on <a href="#">Z</a></li>
</work>
</activity>
</activities>
```

The above one is the XML file. Suppose the file name is activities.xml.

Now I want to parse the data in php. But I want to get the `<b>` and `<a>` tag intact. Means I want to get the line `<b>MR Z</b> working on <a href="#">Z</a>` directly when I parse using li tag. Is that possible? How to get the text with the links and show it?

My php code is something like below:

```
<?php
 $xmls=simplexml_load_file("activities.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xmls as $xml) {
 echo $xml->date;
 echo $xml->work;
}
?>
```

Comment: Mixing HTML and XML like this is going to cause you plenty of problems. Can you edit the source XML? If so, using `<![CDATA[ ... ]>` tags is going to be the best idea.

Comment: Dear thebluefox, thank you. Yes I can edit the xml files. Can you give me more idea please?

Comment: Can you please answer the question in the below link?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859406/how-to-fetch-data-from-xml-in-php-and-create-a-new-page-or-url-in-php-and-show-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [asXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) function to ouput the way you want:

```
foreach ($xmls->activity as $xml) {
    echo $xml->date->asXml();
    echo $xml->work->asXml();
}
```

But the use of `<![CDATA[ ... ]>` is a better choice here, is the correct way to send this kind of data.

Comment: Thank you. It's  great! . :)

Comment: Can you please answer the question in the below link?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859406/how-to-fetch-data-from-xml-in-php-and-create-a-new-page-or-url-in-php-and-show-t

Answer (score 0):

You really need to keep your HTML and you XML separate. You can use `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` in your XML to tell the XML parser there is no XML markup it need needs to worry about.

For example;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activities>
<activity category="Team">
<date><h4>Date: January 15, 2017</h4></date>
<work> 
    <li><![CDATA[<b>MR X</b> working on X]]></li>
    <li><![CDATA[<b>MR Y</b> working on Y]]></li>
    <li><![CDATA[<b>MR Z</b> working on <a href="#">Z</a>]]></li>
</work>
</activity>
</activities>
```

Means that you can loop through `$xml->work` and simply echo the contents of each `<li>` onto the page (I'm presuming that's what you want to do).

---

As an aside, if you do have full control over the XML file, I'd recommend removing as much *HTML-ness* from it. `<li>` means nothing in the context of that XML document.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the matter. But I need to work in these way from xml now. I am sorting out the things.

Comment: Can you please answer the question in the below link?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859406/how-to-fetch-data-from-xml-in-php-and-create-a-new-page-or-url-in-php-and-show-t