# How to fetch data from xml in php and create a new page or url in php and show the full content from xml?

Tags: php, xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <archive>
         <news category="Lorem">
           <headline>Lorem Ipsum</headline>
           <date>January 25th, 2016</date>
           <sortNews>What is Lorem Ipsum?</sortNews>
           <fullNews><b>Lorem Ipsum</b> is simply dummy text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</fullNews>
         </news>
        </archive>
```

The above one is the XML file. Suppose the file name is archive.xml.

```
             <?php
                    $xmls=simplexml_load_file("newsArchive.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
                    foreach ($xmls as $xml) { 
                      echo "<h4>" . $xml->headline->asXml() . "</h4>";
                      echo "<h5>" . $xml->date->asXml() . "</h5>";
                      echo "<p>" . $xml->sortNews->asXml() . "</p>";
                    }
              ?>
```

Now I want to show a link as **read more** after the sortnews and open a new php file or request someting so that it seems like that and show the full news text with others info.

Is that possible to do? Or how can I do that? Also there maybe have multiple news in the xml file.

Comment: what about just writing another php file and putting a link to it? you literally just answered your own question before asking it.

Comment: Yeah. I got that. I already wrote the code :) Thank you.